# JS if statment inside function

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, boolean

i need help please,
im trying to check "if" condition inside a function and print it to the input field
but i always get false, **why this if statement inside the function always return false?**
**and how can i fix it, Thanks.**

```
<body>

    <label>Value1:</label>
    <input id='v1' type="number"><br><br>

    <label>Value2:</label>
    <input id='v2' type="number"><br><br>

    <label>Value3:</label>
    <input id='v3' type="number"><br><br>

    <button onclick="calculateTriangle()">Answer</button>
    <input id='ans'><br><br>

    <script>

    function calculateTriangle() {

        var V1 = document.getElementById('v1').value;
        var V2 = document.getElementById('v2').value;
        var V3 = document.getElementById('v3').value;
        console.log(V1);
        console.log(V2);
        console.log(V3);
        var an = Triangle(V1,V2,V3)
        document.getElementById('ans').value=an;

        }

    function Triangle(a,b,c){

        if (a+b>c && a+c>b && b+c>a){
            return true;
            }
            return false;

            }


    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse your input values as an integer. Use these lines of code instead of yours. The values from your input fields are string.

So when you check `a + b > c` it concatenates `a + b`. Say you put `a = 1` and `b = 2` then it makes `a + b = 12` instead of `3`.

```
 var V1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('v1').value);
 var V2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('v2').value); 
 var V3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('v3').value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (a+b>c && a+c>b && b+c>a){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The else block is redundant, since if the if condition is true the code does not continue past that block because of the return statement.

Comment: `console.log(typeof a, typeof b, typeof c)`, my guess is they are strings.  Using the values 7, 10, 5 should produce true given your logic.